# How to add an on click function to a dynamically created element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, post

I'm aware similar questions have been asked and answered but I can't seem to get them to apply to my issue.

Below is the code that sends an ajax post when the form is submitted

```
  $form.on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: JSON.stringify({ description: desc }),
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {

        $(".list").append(
          '<li><input type="checkbox" value="' +
            data.id +
            '">description</li>"
        );
        createOnClicks(data.id);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        //list errors      },
      complete: function() {
       //reset form
      }
    });
  });
```

this is part of the `createOnClicks()` function:

```
function createOnClicks(id) {
    var listId = "#" + id;

    $(listId).on("click", function(event) {
      var value = $(this).is(":checked");

      if (value) {
        console.log("checked");
        $.ajax({
          url: "/listapi/" + id + "/complete",
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $(listId)
              .parent("li")
              .addClass("complete");
          }
        });
      } else { ... 
    }
});
```

`createOnClicks` works correctly when it is called on elements that are there when the page loads, but won't work on elements that are added with the ajax post.

`$(listId)` returns an empty object when called within `createOnClicks()`, despite on the line above `console.log(listID) shows the appropriate value.

Answer (score 1):

This should apply a click handler to all elements with matching selector even if added after pageload.

```
$(document).on('click', '#list_id', (event)=>{/* some code */})
```

Per comments, this should help do what you need:

```html
<html>
<body>
    <button id="add">add</button>
    <div id="container">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var postHandler = (event)=>{
        console.log('my id is', event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-postid'));
    }
    var number_of_elements = 0;
    document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
        let new_element = document.createElement('div');
        new_element.innerText = "hello";
        new_element.className = "cool_element";
        new_element.setAttribute('data-postid', number_of_elements++);
        new_element.addEventListener('click', postHandler);
        document.getElementById('container').appendChild(new_element);
    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: they all have a different id, list_1, list_2 etc..

Comment: Then use the same class on them all

Comment: @Samantha if you have many elements that need identifying for the same thing use a class instead of IDs. `class="cool_list"` in the element, and `.cool_list` in the selector.

Comment: if you look at the `createOnClicks` function, I need to add an id specific post request for each element.

Comment: @Samantha try using attributes to store data like that. Perhaps `data-postid="1"` when creating the element. Then access in the handler with `event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-postid');` not ideal using substrings of element IDs for that.

Comment: I've tried that, the attribute is available in the function if I do `console.log(listId)` but as soon as it is passed through to `$(listId).on("click", function(event)` it shows an empty object. presumably because the dynamic element hasn't been created yet

Comment: Try accessing through the event passed through. The scope of the variable 'listId' probably not available to the function